# Get 'Normal' .NET Classes to work on Windows 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I normally write a lot of C#/.NET applications, so I figured I'd try out that combination for writing a Windows Store app first. However, I've been having a lot of trouble lately seeing as the classes seem to have developed a habit of disappearing. I've currently tried to write a simple FTP app, but the `FTPWebRequest` class is missing, and when I tried to create a Metro-Style terminal for Cmd, I noticed the `Process` class is missing. Is there any way of getting these classes back?

Comment: I think it would be beneficial for you to learn the general idea behind windows store apps.  A terminal has no place in a windows store app.

Answer (score 1):

In essence, you can't. There may be some related [WinRT classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/br211377.aspx) available, but WinRT apps are sandboxed and don't necessarily have the same flexibility as your normal desktop app.

See for more details: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/05/17/delivering-reliable-and-trustworthy-metro-style-apps.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get them back because they aren't there.  When you create a Windows Store app, you are targeting a different version of the framework.  Another example is when you target the .NET compact framework, the same calls will not be available as in the "normal" framework.